# Java: How can I have one thread add to a queue and another operate on it using threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

Here's what I have:

```
public class Queue implements Runnable {
    ArrayList<Point> queue;

    public Queue(){
        this.queue=new ArrayList<Point>();
    }

    synchronized public void cuePoint(Point p){
        this.queue.add(p);
    }
    synchronized public void doFirstPoint(){
        if(queue.size()!=0){
            //some operation that takes a real long time
            queue.remove(0);
        }
    }

    synchronized public void clearQueue(){
        this.queue.clear();
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true){
            doFirstPoint();
        }
    }
}
```

However, the problem with this code is that if the queue thread is working on a point in the queue (which, as noted, takes a real long time) the cuing thread is kept waiting. Is there a simple, intuitive way to fix this?

Comment: This seems like the classic producer\consumer problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem

Comment: That's correct, a classic producer/consumer scheme. You might really want the cuing thread to wait. If it takes a long time to consume, and you have a multi-core machine, you can leave the queue "outside" with many threads consuming. Also, you should leave the method that removes from que queue synchronized, and do the operation that takes a long time outside the synchronized method, releasing the lock. Take a look at the java.util.concurrent  package, you'll find many helpful classes to implement it (see BlockingQueue)

Comment: Two responses. 1) Don't hold that lock while operating on the "first point". Hold it only long enough to take the object off the queue, releasing the lock before working with the item. 2) Use the out-of-the-box Queue implementations in java.util / java.util.concurrent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a class in java called [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) which does what you are trying to do and it is thread safe.

```
public BlockingQueue<Point> pointQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Point>();
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of this work has been done for you if you use a thread-safe Queue implementation.  I suggest the ArrayBlockingQueue.  The only minor detail, which has advantages and disadvantages is that implementation has a fixed size unlike and ArrayList which can grow infinitely.

```
public abstract class AbstractQueuedRunnable<T> extends Thread
{
    protected BlockingQueue<T> queue;

    public AbstractQueuedRunnable(int maxQueueSize)
    {
        queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<T>(maxQueueSize);
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                T data = queue.take();
                doNext(data);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (e instanceof InterruptedException)
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                else
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void add(T data) throws InterruptedException
    {
        queue.put(data);
    }

    protected abstract void doNext(T data) throws Exception;
}
```

Comment: The treatment of `InterruptedException` is unacceptable here, especially in the `run()` method. Your code swallows the exception in `run()` when it should break out of the loop and exit the method, and in `add()` you swallow the interrupt signal so that a calling thread has no idea what happened. At minimum you should call `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` to restore the interruption status.

Comment: Agreed, have fixed as appropriate.